# String to Int --> Django

Tags: django

[{'age': 1}] being returned something alike to this after a query. This is in my view. Now in my HTML I want to refer to that value returned - in this case '1' if {{}} > 1 ... do something but it cannot do this because Could not parse the remainder: '{{age}}' from '{{age}}'. However if I define a random integer value in my view set it as i.e. 10 I can very easily refer to this variable in my html no problem. I'm presuming it's because it's printing'age' rather than just returning the result from the database. Any solutions to this ? I'm thinking about creating a definition which returns it into a string

Comment: No-one has an answer to this?

Comment: 1) Sometimes, it takes a few hours until someone responds, and 2) after reading your description, I just don't understand what problem you are trying to solve, what you have tried, what happens, and what you expect to happen. You could start by showing us the code that is not working as you expect, and describing in detail what outcome you want instead of the one you get.

Comment: I've tried creating a function which converts it to an int. So basically I am now left with the value '1', returned from my view and I've passed it through. Now say I've given it the variable number.. I want to be able to say {% if {{number}} > 2 %} then do this... but it's not taken a likeness to 'number' even though now I have even converted it to an int .. Could not parse the remainder: '{{number}}' from '{{number}}' when i try do the above if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `{% if number > 2 %}`. You use `{{ number }}` to include a variable in the template, but you don't use the double braces inside a template tag.

Comment: I've tried this and it does not work =/ {% number %} returns 3. Now if I do {% if number > 2 %}
<p>hi</p>
{% endif %} it doesn't return hi =/

Comment: In that case, my guess is that `number` is the string `'3'`, instead of the integer `3`. Please [edit] your question and show your view.

Comment: I converted number to an int by calling this function def int_or_0(value):

 return "{}".format(int(value)) on it  + number = int_or_0(number['lowest_number'])

Comment: Note that `return "{}".format(int(value))` is returning a string. If you want to convert to an integer, return `int(value)`.

Comment: well that was it, god damn - nearly 2 hours wasted! thanks =]